# mypy cannot infer type of generator comprehension correctly

Tags: python, pandas, types, mypy

I am using the stub files provided by *data-science-types* to have mypy be able to check my pandas related code. Sadly I get the following behaviour:

For

```
import pandas as pd

def test() -> pd.DataFrame:
    pass

pd.concat((test() for _ in range(10)))
```

mypy reports
`test.py:6: error: Argument 1 to "concat" has incompatible type "Generator[DataFrame, None, None]"; expected "Union[Sequence[DataFrame], Mapping[str, DataFrame]]".`
If I use `pd.concat([test() for _ in range(10)])` instead mypy is happy again. Can somebody explain to me what's going on there?

Just in case it's relevant. I am using python3.8.5, pandas 1.1.2, mypy 0.782 and data-science-types 0.2.18.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all since the generator expression in my code has SendType and ReturnType of None so `Generator[DataFrame, None, None]` is the correct type see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generator). So as *chepner* has pointed out the problem lies in the expected type. Even though `pandas.concat` excepts generators *data-science-types* does not have it as possible input type for it. I would have considered that a bug but on their [github page](https://github.com/predictive-analytics-lab/data-science-types) *data-science-types* they write

> Philosophy: [...] Often the actual APIs in the libraries is more permissive than the type signatures in our stubs; but this is (usually) a feature and not a bug.

And I consider the problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing a generator with a sequence. A sequence is, [by definition](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence),

> An iterable which supports efficient element access using integer indices via the `__getitem__()` special method and defines a `__len__()` method that returns the length of the sequence.

A generator supports neither, and it's not a kind of mapping, either, so you can't pass one to `pd.concat`.